# How can I speed up my code here? Trying to iterate and replace certain values in every row. Details in body

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I'm trying to modify a pandas dataframe such that in every row, columns `SdLog` and `Meanlog` get updated until a third column, `std`, is less than half of `std_o`. I'm calculating the values within the loop and reducing `sdLog` every time until the calculation is about 50%.

```
for index, row in sf.iterrows():
while sf.loc[index,'std'] > row['std_o']/2:
    z = row['Sdlog'] 
    sf.loc[index, "Sdlog"] = row['Sdlog'] - 0.0001
    sf.loc[index, "Meanlog"] = row['Meanlog'] + (z**2)/2 - (row['Sdlog']**2)/2 
    sf.loc[index, "std"] = ((np.exp((row['Sdlog']**2))-1)*(np.exp(2*(row['Meanlog'])+((row['Sdlog'])**2))))**(.5)
print(row, row['std']/row['std_o'])
```

Can This be **sped** up? Is this the right way? I'd appreciate any help here!

My dataframe looks like this.

```
Activity    Equipment   Meanlog Sdlog   shiftindex  actual_values   std mean    std_o   mean_o
0   Load    CF24    5.83    0.1995  364060  354.779340  69.998462   347.234380  70.147167   347.234380
1   Spot    CF24    3.34    0.6100  364060  61.521021   22.820515   33.989444   22.820515   33.989444
2   Load    CF24    6.33    0.1500  364070  538.410033  85.606872   567.505250  85.606872   567.505250
3   Spot    CF24    3.45    0.3200  364070  24.901455   10.887160   33.155214   10.887160   33.155214
4   Load    CF24    6.04    0.2500  364080  387.610354  110.019983  433.221871  110.019983  433.221871
```

Comment: can you post the dataframe for testing in code not image

Comment: If your code works try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Kenan That sounds great, how can I do that? Sorry new here!

Comment: have a look at np.where, it should work faster than pandas as it is on a lower level: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Comment: Are you sure your code works at all? When I try it, it seems to get stuck because `row['Sdlog']` and `row['Meanlog']` are not actually altered in each iteration

Comment: @Stuart I'm not sure. So if I change it to an `if` loop instead of `while`, the code runs and succesfully updates the values in original dataframe. But when I do while, it doesn't complete for at least 20 mins, so I have not yet to see it work.

Comment: This likely belongs on Code Review Stack Exchange. In any case, there isn't enough here for us to actually run the code.

Comment: The code does not actually work, so this is not for Code Review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see your code is not just slow but gets permanently stuck in the `while` loop because the relevant variables are not actually altered on each iteration. (The values within `sf` are altered but not within the current `row`.) You can make it work by moving the logic to a function that you then apply to each row:

```
def alter(r):
    while r["std"] > r["std_o"] / 2:
        z = r["Sdlog"]
        r["Sdlog"] = r["Sdlog"] - .0001
        r["Meanlog"] = r['Meanlog'] + (z**2)/2 - (r['Sdlog']**2)/2 
        r["std"] = ((np.exp((r['Sdlog']**2))-1)*(np.exp(2*(r['Meanlog'])+((r['Sdlog'])**2))))**(.5)
    return r

altered = sf.apply(alter, axis=1)
```

This works but is slow. Others may be able to suggest optimizations.

EDIT: you can speed it up quite a lot just by separating the maths logic from the code that writes each row.

```
def alter(r):
    r["std"], r["Sdlog"], r["Meanlog"] = change_std(
         s=r["std"],
         so=r["std_o"], 
         sl=r["Sdlog"],
         ml=r["Meanlog"])
    return r

def change_std(s, so, sl, ml):
    ch = .0001
    ch2 = .5 * ch * ch
    s2 = s * s
    target = so * so / 4
    while s2 > target:
        ml += ch * sl - ch2  # this simplifies ml += sl**2/2 - (sl-ch)**2/2
        sl -= ch
        s2 = (np.exp(sl*sl) - 1) * np.exp(2*ml + sl*sl)
    return s2 ** .5, sl, ml
```

Looking at the algorithm written like this I guess you could speed it up further by starting with a large `ch` and reducing it each time you overshoot the desired value of `s` of approximately `so/2`.

Comment: This does work! Thank you, glad to know it's actually doable in this way. But as you mentioned, it is very slow.

Comment: Wow, thank you!! It really works well now. You are a whiz.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tested (on the sample):

```py
    frame['logic']= frame['std']>(frame['std_o']/2)
    frame['Sdlog'] = np.where(frame['logic'], frame['Sdlog']-0.0001, frame['Sdlog'])
    frame["Meanlog"] = np.where(frame['logic'],frame['Meanlog'] + (frame['Sdlog']**2)/2 - (frame['Sdlog']**2)/2 , frame['Meanlog'])
    frame['std'] = np.where(frame['logic'], ((np.exp((frame['Sdlog']**2))-1)*(np.exp(2*(frame['Meanlog'])+((frame['Sdlog'])**2))))**(.5), frame['std'])


result per 1000 iterations: 2.7607345581054688s
```

```py
#original

    for index, row in frame.iterrows():
        while frame.loc[index,'std'] > row['std_o']/2:
            z = row['Sdlog'] 
            frame.loc[index, "Sdlog"] = row['Sdlog'] - 0.0001
            frame.loc[index, "Meanlog"] = row['Meanlog'] + (z**2)/2 - (row['Sdlog']**2)/2 
            frame.loc[index, "std"] = ((np.exp((row['Sdlog']**2))-1)*(np.exp(2*(row['Meanlog'])+((row['Sdlog'])**2))))**(.5)


result per 1000 iterations: >60s, interrupted.
```

Please note I worked only with the small sample and haven't really checked if the results are correct.

Comment: thank you! This runs fast, but is the equivalent of an if loop instead of while. As in, it only runs once and terminates - any suggestions on how to make it run **until** the value is less than half, not just if?

Comment: @TJB There is no need for a loop, when you build frame[logic], it will contain an array of True/False for the indexes where the condition is True or False respectively. np.where works with this array in a single parsing, and evaluets the condition for all the elements in the array at once

Comment: I see. But it still only runs once. Example, when it runs it changes the value of `Sdlog` by (-.0001), but `std` is still greater than half of `std_o`. It doesn't update till completion. Does that make sense?

Comment: @TJB, wherever the condition is false, the calculation is just ignored. Do you have a specific order in your data and want the program to stop at the first encounter (even if the condition may be true later)?

Comment: @TJB ,This shouldn't happen, np.where goes though the whole array. I might have messed up the logic of course, though. It works for the whole array on the sample.

Comment: you do not need a loop, it does it in one run

Comment: Your code has maybe a typo in the numerical value. It should be .0001 not .001, which I believe will give you a different answer as it needs to run several times to get `Sdlog` to the right value

Comment: Shouldn't be significant. edited the answer anyway.

Comment: @TJB, I think I got it, do you want to run it utill there are no ['std_o']/2 in the whole array?